# Pattern Matching performance in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have such a type `type 'a tree = Node of int * 'a * 'a tree`

The `int` part is the `rank`.

Also I have a function `let rank = function Node (r, _, _) -> r`.

Suppose in my real code, I have lots of places that need to access the `rank` of a node, and much of the time, the `rank` of same nodes.

My question is that Should I always use `rank t` function directly or should I give the rank of a t to, say, `r`, then use `r`?

For example, I can do

```
if rank t1 < rank t2 then Node (rank t1 + 1, 5, t1)
else Node (rank t2 + 1, 5, t2)
```

or

```
let r1 = rank t1 in let r2 = rank t2 in
if r1 < r2 then Node (r1+1, 5, t1) else Node (r2, 5, t2)
```

What is the performance diff? And which way is better and why?

Comment: Note that you can shorten `let r1 = rank t1 in let r2 = rank t2 in` to `let r1 = rank t1 and r2 = rank t2 in` or even `let r1, r2 = rank t1, rank t2 in`. The last form is optimized IIRC to be equivalent to the other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using let to avoid computing the rank twice is better. I don't think the OCaml compiler optimizes calling the same function twice; it would require some kind of effect analysis.

I'd be glad to be wrong though ;)

Comment: Inlining followed by CSE would be enough for this particular case, but I don't think OCaml does much of either at the moment.